# how I can filter duplicate results from the jsonarray by java 8 Lambda

Tags: java, filter, lambda, collectors, distinct-values

I have below jasonArry and I need to filter the unique results based on **identifier** values

Below is the JSONArray which I got from a different API, I need to filter this JSONArray

```
JSONArray 


{
    "data": [
        [{
                "datatype": "DeviceDataUse",
                "values": {

                    "ensembleid": "194252612743",
                    "averagerating": "4.5",
                    "identifier": "dvc13080026prd",
                    "reviewcount": "",
                    "commentcount": ""
                }
            }, {
                "datatype": "DeviceSkuDataUse",
                "values": {
                    "identifier": "146200104",
                    "imagecount": "4",
                    "hexcode": "#DDDFDE",
                    "ensembleid": "194252612743"
                },
                "pageUrl": ""
            }, {
                "datatype": "DeviceDataUse",
                "values": {
                    "ensembleid": "194252697634",
                    "averagerating": "4.5",
                    "identifier": "dvc13470044prd",
                    "reviewcount": "96",
                    "commentcount": "0"
                }
            }, {
                "datatype": "DeviceSkuDataUse",
                "values": {
                    "identifier": "146202344",
                    "imagecount": "4",
                    "hexcode": "#DDDFDE",
                    "ensembleid": "194654612743"
                },
                "pageUrl": ""
            }, {
                "datatype": "DeviceDataUse",
                "values": {
                    "ensembleid": "194200097634",
                    "averagerating": "4.5",
                    "identifier": "dvc13478844prd",
                    "reviewcount": "96",
                    "commentcount": "0"
                }
            }, {
                "datatype": "DeviceSkuDataUse",
                "values": {
                    "identifier": "100002344",
                    "imagecount": "4",
                    "hexcode": "#DDDFDE",
                    "ensembleid": "194654000043"
                },
                "pageUrl": ""
            },
            {
                "datatype": "DeviceDataUse",
                "values": {

                    "ensembleid": "194252612743",
                    "averagerating": "4.5",
                    "identifier": "dvc13080026prd",
                    "reviewcount": "",
                    "commentcount": ""
                }
            }, {
                "datatype": "DeviceSkuDataUse",
                "values": {
                    "identifier": "146200104",
                    "imagecount": "4",
                    "hexcode": "#DDDFDE",
                    "ensembleid": "194252612743"
                },
                "pageUrl": ""
            }

        ]
    ]
}
```

We can use java 8 Lambda,

`
Tried a couple of things but not get unique results based on identifier

`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: what is your filtering criteria

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Gson for this. Gson is a Java Json serialization library.

Here is an example test doing something similar to what you want to achieve using `Gson`, `Lombok` and `JUnit`:

```
public class JsonArrayFilteringTest {

    @Data
    class JsonElement {
        private String datatype;
        private Map<String,String> values;
    }

    @Data
    class JsonData {
        private List<JsonElement> data;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final String jsonStr = "your json data...";


        final JsonData jsonData = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonStr, JsonData.class);
        final long numberOfOccurrences = jsonData.getData().stream()
                .map(element -> element.values)
                .filter(value -> value.containsKey("identifier") && value.get("identifier").equals("dvc13080026prd"))
                .count();

        assertEquals(2, numberOfOccurrences);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect using Collectors toMap and retrieve the values. Example using Jackson and reading only the array

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) objectMapper.readTree(jsonArray);

StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(arrayNode.elements(), 0), false)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                element -> element.get("values").get("identifier").asText(), // key
                Function.identity(), // element
                (first, second) -> first)) // function to handle duplicates
        .values()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy Dsilva, Thanks for helping me on this,                                                     
I am getting the below error, when I am trying to pass jsonArray in readTree, readTree supports only  JsonParser.

ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) objectMapper.readTree(jsonArray);

Error: 
The method readTree(JsonParser) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (JSONArray)

Comment: Are you using Jackson? The use of Jackson is to demonstrate a working example using Streams. You will need to modify the code based on the JSON library you are using.

Comment: Yes I am using Jackson

Comment: What is the type of JSONArray?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach -

```
1) Iterate over the array using stream.

2) Maintain a Set<String> ( say identifierSet) which stores the identifier value.

3) In the filter method extract the identifier(you can use 
jsonPath for this) and check if identifierSet contains the current 
identifier.

If contains, return false 

Else add the identifier to the identifierSet and return true.

4) use collect method to collect the distinct values.
```